# subscript out of range error, macro that runs through all files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

Can I please receive an assistance in rewriting the code attached below so that I can avoid using the **ws As Worksheet ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("newreport") 'change the name of the sheet to the one you are doing the code**

```
Dim arrData As Variant, LastRow As Long, i As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("newreport") 'change the name of the sheet to the one you are doing the code

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        arrData = .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 3) Like "Bus*" Then
                arrData(i, 1) = "XX XXX"
            Else
                arrData(i, 1) = "XXX XX"
            End If
            If arrData(i, 3) Like "CSI*" Or arrData(i, 3) = vbNullString Then
                arrData(i, 2) = vbNullString
            Else
                arrData(i, 2) = Right(arrData(i, 3), Len(arrData(i, 3)) - 12)
            End If
        Next i
        .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value = arrData
    End With

  For Each cell In Range("B2", Range("B605536").End(xlUp))
If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
cell.Value = Right(cell, Len(cell) - 2)
End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to loop through multiple sheets in the same workbook and apply the same logic?

Comment: @BradDixon hey brad, no. The goal is to have a macro saved in an excel file. The user saves another file into a folder. This user will then open the excel file with the macro, run it. which will run a macro on the file in the folder.

Comment: ok, understood, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets you going ...

```
Public Sub OpenOtherWorkbooksAndProcess()
    Dim objDlg As FileDialog, strFolder As String, objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder, objFile As Scripting.File, objBook As Workbook

    Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set objDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    objDlg.Show

    If objDlg.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        strFolder = objDlg.SelectedItems(1)

        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            ' You may want to change this to check for the type of files.
            ' The assumption is that all files within the selected folder are excel files.
            Set objBook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)

            ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ' ADD YOU LOGIC USING objBook AS YOUR SOURCE WORKBOOK
            ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------                

            objBook.Save
            objBook.Close
        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

... does that help?

It may need tweaks to cater for your exact scenario but it's the baseline for doing what (I think) you want.

You will need to add a reference to the library as shown below ...

[image: Microsoft Scripting Runtime]